# First order Nonlinear ODE that is not separable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a first order, nonlinear ODE: $$x\frac{dy}{dx} - y\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2xy}{x+y}$$ which I have turned into this: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2xy}{(x^2 - y^2)}$$ I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, since I don't see any immediate way to use the method of integrating factors or Leibniz transformation.

Edit: I'm looking for a method to solve for y(x), maybe something I haven't learned yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Hint** The problem could be simple working with $x(y)$ and letting $x(y)=\sqrt{z(y)}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that hint would make a very good answer since OP is already familiar with solving first order linear equations with integrating factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, switching variables gives
$$x' = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{2xy}\implies 2xx'=\frac{x^2 - y^2}{y}\implies (x^2)'=\frac{x^2 - y^2}{y} $$ Let $z=x^2$ to face
$$z'=\frac{z - y^2}{y}\implies y\, z'-z=-y^2$$ which looks to be simple.

When done, just inverse to get $y$ as a function of $x$

Comment: Once i did that I got x^2 = -yln(y) + Cy, and I'm not sure how to get just y = f(x)

Comment: @Johnathan.  Sorry for the typo ! The rhs is $-y^2$ and not $-y$

Comment: Dang i should have noticed that. Thanks!